# Unexpected behavior in Stack Overflow Trends

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonym-process, trends

I'm using [Stack Overflow Trends](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/) to track the popularity of several tags. In particular, I'm very interested in monitoring the [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tag. Currently, this chart is as follows:

[image]

https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=selenium

As you can see, there is an abrupt fall to 0 during the last months. But this is not true. There are still a lot of Stack Overflow questions that use the tag [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium).

I suspect the cause is that, nowadays, the tag [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) is a synonym of [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium

This way, the evolution of the [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) tag has experienced a peak during the last month:

[image]

https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=selenium%2Cselenium-webdriver

I would like this "issue" to be fixed somehow. For that, I have two requests:

1. I would like to see the first chart (the one using the tag [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium)) displaying the data that the second char (the one using the tag [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver)) has stolen.
2. I think that two tags, [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium), and [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), should be possible. Selenium is the umbrella project (i.e., a set of tools for browser automation). [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) (which is the heart of the project, that's true) is the library for driving browsers programmatically.

Comment: it looks like that synonym got suggested by a user and then got 5 votes to get it in place. What tools / question would benefit from having only the selenium tag and not the selenium-webdriver tag? Looking at the tag list I see a lot of the tools covered so I guess all SMEs will still find the questions they want to answer. I'm not opposed to having the umbrella but if it is of little value except for Insight issues I would think the synonym is fine.

Comment: Maybe the synonym is fine. But what is wrong, IMO, is the fact that StackOverflow Trends stop tracking a tag because it is a synonym of another. Perhaps this is a bug in the way in which StackOverflow Trends counts.